# Android Custom Launcher startActivity() blocks BOOT_COMPLETED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-source, start-activity

I am currently working on a custom ROM (based on CyanogenMod 11.0), which aims to implement a custom "Kiosk Mode". To do this, I have three components in one application (with system privileges): The service, which handles modifications to the status/navigationbar and disables the power key. The receiver, which only starts the service after the `BOOT_COMPLETED` signal is received. The `HomeIntentWrapper` works as the launcher, and only starts one custom activity.

The problem I am currently facing is that the `startActivity(...)` command in the `HomeIntentWrapper` somehow blocks the system from booting any further, and the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent is never sent.

I verifed this with the `adb shell dumpsys activity` command, which tells me:

```
mStartedUsers:
  User #0: mState=BOOTING
```

It also does not show the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast ever sent.

Now, if the user presses the Home-Button, the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent is sent, and the `mState` switches to `RUNNING`.

If I do not start an activity in the `HomeIntentWrapper`, the intent is sent. What am I doing wrong here?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest coreApp="true">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />    

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:persistent="true" >

        <service android:name="Service" 
                 android:process=":service" >
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="Receiver" 
                  android:process=":receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="HomeIntentWrapper"
                  android:process=":launcher" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Service.class));
    }
}
```

HomeIntentWrapper:

```
public class HomeIntentWrapper extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startApp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startApp();
    }

    private void startApp() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.settings_file), Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        String customAppIntentString = sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.settings_custom_intent), "");

        if(customAppIntentString.equals("") == false) {
            try {
                Intent intent = Intent.getIntent(customAppIntentString);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(java.net.URISyntaxException e) {
                // Intentionally
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root cause: finishBooting() is not called because Home Activity is not on top of stack.

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStackSupervisor.java

Line: 1811
Line: 1883-1886
Line: 1934-1940

Solution:

Do not call start Activity Until Boot_Completed is received.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. I have this situation where ActivityManagerService#finishBooting() is not called (making BOOT_COMPLETED not sent) because ActivityManagerService#systemReady() is sometimes called after ActivityStackSupervisor#activityIdleInternalLocked(). Now, systemReady() sets mBooting=true, and it has to be set to true before activityIdleInternalLocked() checks it in order to call finishBooting(). Seems likte there is a race-condition going on because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Do you have any idea what might be going on?